# Netsuite - REPLACE function replaces enitre field - not just the character I want to replace

Tags: sql, netsuite

In Netsuite I have a mass update to replace all single quotes with the number 20.

I am using the below formula thanks to someone's assistance here earlier but what is happening is the entire text field is being replaced.

```
REPLACE(CHR(39) || '20', CHR(39) , '20')
```

For example - the field I am mass updating has the following:

```
Vacation '20
```

Using the above formula instead of getting:

```
Vacation 2020
```

I am getting:

```
2020
```

How can I only replace the single quote but leave all else intact?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the formula to include the entire text field in the first argument of the `REPLACE()` function.  Something like:

```
REPLACE({customfield_containing_text_with_single_quote}, CHR(39) , '20')
```